# Origem da palavra 'demão'

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem

Segundo os dicionários ***demão*** significa:

> camada de tinta, cal, etc., que se aplica numa superfície [(Infopédia)](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dem%C3%A3o)

É amplamente utilizado no Brasil, segundo o site [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/segunda-demao-de-tinta/29636), é um brasileirismo. Por outro lado, segundo o mesmo site, há dicionários em Portugual que também trazem o significado dessa palavra sem menção ao Brasil. Dessa forma, entendo que é utilizada também em outros países.

Quando essa palavra começou a ser usada? E por uma simplificação de fala, como *Vosmicê*, por exemplo?

Comment: *Demão* não é brasileirismo: é usado com o mesmo significado em Portugal. O que segundo o Ciberdúvidas, ou melhor, segundo o Houaiss, é brasileirismo é *mão* com o significado de *demão*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Demão*** vem literalmente de ***de mão***, e ***mão*** significa aqui o mesmo que *demão*. Veja-se por exempo *mão* no dicionário [Morais Silva de 1858](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lTBxS8oISF4C&pg=PA329&dq=%22Outros%20dizem%20uma%20dem%C3%A3o%20de%20tinta%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAr6XymKnVAhWKChoKHdE6DMoQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Outros%20dizem%20uma%20dem%C3%A3o%20de%20tinta%22&f=false) ou no seguinte dicionário de artes de 1875 (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> MÃO DE TINTA, phrase vulgar, camada de tinta, e diz- se primeira **mão ou demão** de tinta, segunda, terceira **mão ou demão**, pôr ou dar a ultima **mão ou demão**; acabar bem uma obra d'arte, concluil-a com perfeição.
> [Francisco de Assis Rodrigues, *Diccionario Technico e Historico de Pintura*...  Lisboa, 1875.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YptAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA250&dq=%22m%C3%A3o%20ou%20dem%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp29LgrPrTAhVL0hoKHZ8aDIEQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22m%C3%A3o%20ou%20dem%C3%A3o%22&f=false)

E ao longo do século XIX e até mesmo princípio do século XX encontramos *demão* escrito também separadamente, ***de mão***,

Por exemplo, “dar-se-ha huma de mão de lacca” [(*Annaes das Sciencias*, 1819)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qf9JAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA53&dq=%22%20dar-Sfc-ha%20huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20de%20lacca%20moida%20com%20oleo%20desecante%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK3OmdoanVAhUBuxQKHTx3CgAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%20dar-Sfc-ha%20huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20de%20lacca%20moida%20com%20oleo%20desecante%22&f=false), “huma de mão d'oleo de linhaça quente” [(Francisco Rubião, 1844)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=09ZhAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA206&dq=%22huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20d%27oleo%20de%20linha%C3%A7a%20quente%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2la6Mo6nVAhWDORoKHbngBVQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20d%27oleo%20de%20linha%C3%A7a%20quente%22&f=false), “uma de mão de terebentina” [(*Agricultor Brazileiro*, 1853)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OhNAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20de%20terebentina%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMsMbppqnVAhXHPRoKHaQfC7MQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%20de%20terebentina%22&f=false), ou ainda em [1932 na *Língua Portugusea, revista de filologia:*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8EorAAAAIAAJ&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM39CE56fVAhWOzRoKHe_HBckQ6AEIJTAA)

> **«Uma de mão»**. É a camada de tinta ou de cal, que se aplica, a pincel, nas superfícies a pintar ou caiar; e também a pequena ajuda para se carregar um cântaro à cabeça ou um fardo às costas.

*Mão* é, mesmo nesta aceção, o termo original e evoluíu já dum significado relacionado do latim *manus*; tanto que os cognatos castelhano *mano* [(aceção 11, Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy) e italiano *mano* [(aceção 3, Corriere dela Sera)](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mano.shtml) também significam camada de tinta, verniz, etc. Os falantes de português parecem ter sido os únicos que se lembraram de acrescentar *de* a *mão*. A razão por que o fizeram já é debatida há século e meio, sem se ter chegado a uma conclusão definitiva. Dou pormenores mais abaixo, mas vamos primeiro ao latim.

Já se encontra em autores romanos as expressões *manus extrema* e *ultimam manum* com o significado de ‘retoque final’. Veja-se este [*A Latin Dictionary* de Charlton T. Lewis e Charles Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmanus1) (minha tradução do inglês):

> **B.** Acerca da mão do artista: “manus extrema non accessit ejus operibus,” *a última mão, o retoque final,* Cic. Brut. 33, 126 […] “carmen nondum recepit ultimam manum,” *ainda não levou o último polimento,* Petr. 118.—Deste modo, extremam bello Imponere manum, *pôr a mão finalizante na guerra, fazê-la acabar,* Verg. A. 7, 573.

*Mão* é aqui metonimicamente usado no lugar de ‘trabalho feito pela mão’. Este uso de *mão* passou ao português, espanhol e italiano, não só na expressão *última mão*, mas também *primeira mão, segunda mão,* etc., referindo-se a cada uma das vezes que se começa ou se retoma o trabalho numa obra. Veja-se a aceção 18 no dicionário da [Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy), a 3 do [Vocabolario on line Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mano) (é melhor fazer Ctr F “fasi do lavoro”) e novamente o [Morais Silva de 1858:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lTBxS8oISF4C&pg=PA329&dq=%22Dar%20a%20segunda%20m%C3%A3o;%20loc.%20fig,%20retocar%20a%20obra%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiytaz0xanVAhUCthQKHXnjC-AQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Dar%20a%20segunda%20m%C3%A3o%3B%20loc.%20fig%2C%20retocar%20a%20obra%22&f=false) ou o [*Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* de Domingos Vieira (1873)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WhZnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=%22A%20ultima%20m%C3%A3o;%20o%20ultimo%20trabalho%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR_eK0xqnVAhVDvBQKHXuGDY4Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22A%20ultima%20m%C3%A3o%3B%20o%20ultimo%20trabalho%22&f=false)

> —*A ultima* mão; o ultimo trabalho, aquelle que acaba uma obra.—*Dar a ultima* mão; aperfeiçoar, acabar.
> —*Dar a segunda* mão; retocar a obra.

A aceção ‘aplicação de tinta, cola, gesso, etc.’ é apenas um uso especializado deste sentido mais lato de *mão*. O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) ainda traz este sentido lato de *mão*—“**19** *B p.us.* cada uma das vezes que se torna a tratar de um assunto ou a fazer algo”—mas restringe-o ao Brasil e diz que é pouco usado. O mesmo sentido lato é atribuído a *demão*, sem quaiquer restrições; vem também no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dem%C3%A3o) e [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dem%C3%A3o)

O primeiro exemplo que descobri de *mão* neste sentido foi uma citação de do artista [Francisco de Holanda (1517-85)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_de_Holanda) no [dicionário de artes de Francisco Assis Rodrigues:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kgQGyTgu3MYC&pg=PA136&dq=%22primeira%20dem%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsx5CQr__TAhXIUBQKHRPHCYM4MhDoAQivAjAq#v=onepage&q=%22primeira%20dem%C3%A3o%22&f=false)

> […] se posibel for ante q̃ a obra não steja acabada não deve de ser vista de algũa pesoa, mas depois della cõ a ***strema mão*** ser acabada então seja ella p.ª a poder ver o mundo todo.

Depois temos “dar a ultima mão a esta obra” [(Fr. Bernardo de Brito, 1597)](http://purl.pt/14843/3/#/9) e “dar a ultima mão a hũa imagẽ” [(Rafael de Jesus, 1683)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EBNUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP9&dq=%22dar%20a%20ultima%20m%C3%A3o%20a%20h%C3%BAa%20imag%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO9NzczKnVAhVGVxoKHYXsCegQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22dar%20a%20ultima%20m%C3%A3o%20a%20h%C3%BAa%20imag%C3%A9%22&f=false).

***Demão*** encontra-se quase tão cedo, num relato de [Tomé Pinheiro da Veiga (1566/71 – 1656)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom%C3%A9_Pinheiro_da_Veiga). Ele faz uma descrição maravilhosa duma dama portuguesa, Francisca de Aragão [(citação neste livro)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tnxyCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=%22dem%C3%A3o%20de%20unto%22&source=bl&ots=59nhWyRHFq&sig=EtcS_AsCX6QX0mU88OuWTpt9VYI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd78igvfrTAhWNSxoKHXkFCOYQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22dem%C3%A3o%20de%20unto%22&f=false):

> «Cabelos tintos de açafrão e as pestanas de verniz, o rosto de almagra, a garganta de gesso e a boca de cetim, toda a óleo, com uma **demão de unto de porco**, e outra de manteiga crua… é a mais querida e amada senhora que há na Corte, e mais conhecida e respeitada Dama, que todas.»

No século XIX encontram-se em abundância quer *demão* quer *de mão* quer simplesmente *mão*. Mas ao contrário do que se passava comigo, que não fazia ideia que *demão* viesse de *de mão*, o pessoal da altura parecia esta consciente disso. Nos dicionários anteriores ao de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1899 não encontrei um verbete para *demão*; a palavra aparece no verbete *mão*. E muita gente escreve separadamente *de mão*.

### **Debate sobre o acrescento do *de***

Encontrei a primeira discussão do assunto numa carta dum leitor à revista [*Archivo Pittoresco* (Lisboa, 1865)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=K7M9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA352&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQppLV3KfVAhVE8RQKHacwBfQQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&f=false):

> Ultimamente occorreu escrever eu: «O drama está todo traduzido já; só lhe falta a ultima *de mão*.»
> Notaram-me isto de corruptela do vulgo, e que devia dizer a *ultima mão.*
> É certo que Moraes no *Dicc.* assim o ensina […]
> Mas para evitar o cacófato *(mamão)* creio que podêmos muito bem inserir a preposição *de,*, como faz o vulgo, que tambem tem ouvido. E demais conforma-se isto com a doutrina que v. expendeu, de que a eufonia da nossa língua permitte estas e outras similhantes liberdades, no tocante ás particulas que não alteram o sentido da oração. […]
> [Estudos da Lingua Materna, 77.ª carta”, *Archivo Pittoresco*, vol 8, nº 44, Lisboa, 1865.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=K7M9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA352&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQppLV3KfVAhVE8RQKHacwBfQQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&f=false)

Na revista respondem-lhe que sim, que é uma boa ideia introduzir o *de* para evitar a cacofonia. Curiosamente sessenta anos mais tarde a mesma questão é colocada exatamente nas mesmas palavras à [*Revista de Língua Portuguesa* (Rio de Janeiro, 1925)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22me%20indagar%20sobre%20a%20express%C3%A3o%22&oq=%22me%20indagar%20sobre%20a%20express%C3%A3o%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...34604.34604.0.36278.1.1.0.0.0.0.123.123.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.UtXztkrXOEc) (para completar a discussão, [excerto 2](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aZnNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22me%20indagar%20sobre%20a%20express%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22me%20indagar%20sobre%20a%20express%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH-4GZ9anVAhVRlxQKHZk2CGoQ6AEIJTAA) mais [3](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aZnNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22primeira%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22primeira%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRi5-n7afVAhUJfhoKHZZrAWwQ6AEIJTAA), [4](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&lr=lang_pt&biw=1366&bih=662&tbs=lr%3Alang_1pt%2Csbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_max%3A1950&tbm=bks&q=%22segunda%20de%20m%C3%A3o%2C%20etc.%20%E2%80%94%20em%20que%20n%C3%A3o%22&oq=%22segunda%20de%20m%C3%A3o%2C%20etc.%20%E2%80%94%20em%20que%20n%C3%A3o%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...617829.617829.0.619658.1.1.0.0.0.0.226.226.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.tMcRkSFiEP0), [6](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aZnNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22segunda%20de%20m%C3%A3o,%20etc.%20%E2%80%94%20em%20que%20n%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22segunda%20de%20m%C3%A3o,%20etc.%20%E2%80%94%20em%20que%20n%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2r--D9qnVAhUCXhoKHWLHAE8Q6AEIJTAA), [7](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22pobre%20do%20homem%3A%20triste%20do%20menino%22&oq=%22pobre%20do%20homem%3A%20triste%20do%20menino%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3607.3607.0.5003.1.1.0.0.0.0.67.67.1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0._KkNBqtY0s8), [8](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aZnNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM39CE56fVAhWOzRoKHe_HBckQ6AEIKzAB) e [9](https://www.google.pt/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22ora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20sem%20que%20o%20sentido%20se%20altere%22)) A opinião na revista foi que:

> […] não foi para evitar o cacophato que se inseriu a particula — *de* —entre — *uma* — e — *mão.*
> E não o foi, porque a expressão — *de mão* — se usa em *primeira de mão, segunda de mão*, etc. — em que não existe o tal *mamão*
> […]
> Considerar o vocabulo — de — como particula de realce ou expletiva, á semelhança das construções conhecidas — *pobre do homem: triste do menino; deu-lhe o nome de Pedro; feliz de quem morre.*
> Penso que a melhor explicação será a que considera — de — como particula de realce, principalmente porque se verifica com este vocabulo na frase — dar uma de mão — o que acontece geralmente com as particulas de realce : podem ser tiradas da oração sem que o sentido se altere e por fim permanecem na lingua crystallizadas e somente empregadas em certas frases com um sentido determinado e unico.
> [*Revista de Língua Portuguesa*, vol. 6, Rio de Janeiro, 1925, p. 71 e 72.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aZnNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22primeira%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22primeira%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRi5-n7afVAhUJfhoKHZZrAWwQ6AEIJTAA)

Não me parece o argumento válido: o *de* poderia ter sido introduzido para desfazer o cacófano nas expressões *uma mão* e *última mão*, e mais tarde passar a usar-se também em *segunda, terceira mão*. Mas a ideia de *de* ser partícula de realce não me parece menos meritória, e as duas ideias não são incompatíveis.

Por sua vez, [José Joaquim Nunes (1859 – 1932)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biografias/jjnunes.html) diz em *Digressões Lexicológicas* (citado em [Antenor Nascentes, *Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguêsa*, Rio de Janeiro, 1955]):

> A preposição *de*, que se juntou a *mão* formando uma palavra só, entrou aqui provavelmente como na locução popular *última da hora*.

Isto não adianto muito por aí além, porque não sabemos como é que o *da* entrou na expressão *última hora*. No entanto isto sugere-me uma ideia. É a minha contribuição pessoal para o debate.

Eu uso a expressão *última da hora* (e não *última hora*), mas ao contrário do caso de *demão* estou consciente da preposição. E ela leva-me a interpretar a exprssão *última da hora* como ‘fim da hora’, em que *hora* é aqui intepretado com período de tempo e não momento exato (como em “vou lá durante a hora do almoço”). É como se houvesse um certo período durante o qual a pessoa pudesse chegar, por exemplo, e ela chaga mesmo no fim, à última da hora. É como se houvesse uma entidade feminina [?] implícita na expressão: *última [?] da hora*. O facto de todos os substantivo que eu podesse introduzir ali serem masculinos—minuto, segundo, instante, momnento—não me impede que eu sinta a expressão desse modo.

Ora há uma porção de expressões na nossa língua em que parece haver uma tal entidade feminina [?] implícita:

> Eles estão numa [?] boa.
> Estou numa [?] de ir hoje jantar fora.
> Essa [?] é boa!
> Ora essa [?]!
> Agora é que arranjaste a [?] bonita.
> Chegou à última [?] da hora.
> Essa parede precisa de mais uma [?] de mão.

No caso de *dar uma [?] mão* até poderíamos supôr *dar uma passagem de mão*, mas acho pouco provável que alguém tenha dito isso. Parece-me me mais plausível que *dar uma de mão* fizesse sentido, estando o locutor consciente do *de*, tal como as outras expressões acima fazem sentido para quem as diz.

Note-se que [*dar uma mão* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/m%C3%A3o) também significa ‘ajudar’, o que se compreende lindamente. Ora no passado também aqui se acrescentou um *de*, dizendo-se *dar uma de mão*, tal como já poderão ter reparado nalgumas das minhas citações, como a da [*Língua Portugusea, revista de filologia* (1932)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8EorAAAAIAAJ&q=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22uma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM39CE56fVAhWOzRoKHe_HBckQ6AEIJTAA), que eu repito aqui:

> **«Uma de mão»**. É a camada de tinta ou de cal, que se aplica, a pincel, nas superfícies a pintar ou caiar; e também a pequena ajuda para se carregar um cântaro à cabeça ou um fardo às costas.

Aqui ainda a ideia da tal entidade me parece mais convincene: “dá-me aqui uma [?] de mão com esta fardo”. Também este uso é antigo, e não foi só para ajudar a pôr um cântaro à cabeça ou um fardo às costas que se usou *dar uma de mão*. Aqui temos o Padre António Vieira em 1652:

> Demos huma de mão aos Berlanguches, já que lha promettemos; e eles naõ querem, que lhes faltemos com o promettido.
> [Padre António Vieira, *Arte de Furtar, Espelho de Enganos, Theatro de Verdades, Mostrador de Horas Minguadas,* Amesterdão, 1652.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5KdlAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA303&dq=%22huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ7oGpnKnVAhXLXRoKHX65CnwQ6AEIUjAG#v=onepage&q=%22huma%20de%20m%C3%A3o%22&f=false)